# Simple laravel models usage

Tags: php, laravel

My model:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Products';
    protected $fillable = ['product_code', 'type', 'name', 'description', 'price', 'discount', 'image', 'image_alt'];

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\ProductSpecifics');
    }
}
```

My controller code:

```
public function product($code)
{
    $product = Product::where('product_code',$code)->get();
    $productSpec = ProductSpecifics::where('product_code',$code)->get();
    var_dump($product->name);
    return view('pages.product', compact('product','productSpec'));
}
```

Error:
**Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance**

I tried using dd($product) and I noticed that there is a lot of information in there.[image: dd response]

How do I extract only the attributes like name,type & etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
dd($product->toArray());
```

Comment: Your solution + replacing `->get()` to `->first()` gives me this: https://imgur.com/ipLsXsO , but for some reason, I still can't access `$productArray->name`

Comment: you are getting records using ```$product = Product::where('product_code',$code)->get();```,  you have to iterate in foreach loop to access property.

Comment: to access property without looping use ```$product = Product::where('product_code',$code)->first();``` instead. but it will return only first record.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned above, that's what I did, but I still can't simply access them.

Comment: use exactly this ```$product = Product::where('product_code',$code)->first();
dd($product->name);```

Comment: if converted to array use this ```$product = Product::where('product_code',$code)->first()->toArray();
dd($product['name']);```